# How to reuse action creators in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-functions, reducers

My question is about how to structure reducers and actions creators in order to reuse them correctly. 
I've read tons of bibliography in the web about reducers composition and higher order reducers and managed to get some steps into the correct direction by creating a namespaced reducer factory/generator. With this i can have different instances of the same component/view with independent states, that share common behaviour. However this is not true for components/views that have the share some common grounds but are not equal. Lets say... the show and edit view for an entity.

On mount, both of this components needs to fetch the entity data from an API in the same way, however the show component has much less features than the edit component which also processes form submit, handles errors, etc...

So, having said that... how i'm suppose to extend the editEntityReducer and editEntity action creators to include the entityReducer and entity action creators plus the edits own reducer features and action creators?

This is what i have so far, using a User entity as an example:

## User reducer + action creators (user.js):

```
import normalize from 'jsonapi-normalizer'
import { api, authenticatedHeaders } from 'api'
import { RSAA } from 'redux-api-middleware'
import { List, Record } from 'immutable'
import * as constants from './constants'

// ------------------------------------
// Actions
// ------------------------------------
export const destroyUser = (userId) => {
  // Uses redux-api-middleware. see: https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: api.users.destroy.path(userId),
      method: api.users.destroy.method,
      headers: (state) => authenticatedHeaders(state.session.authorization.token),
      types: [
      constants.DESTROY_START,
      constants.DESTROY_SUCCESS,
      constants.DESTROY_FAIL]
    }
  }
}

export const fetchUser = (userId) => {
  // Uses redux-api-middleware. see: https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: api.users.show.path(userId),
      method: api.users.show.method,
      headers: (state) => authenticatedHeaders(state.session.authorization.token),
      types: [
      constants.FETCH_START,
      {
        type: constants.FETCH_SUCCESS,
        payload: (action, state, res) => {
          return res.json().then(json => normalize(json))
        }
      },
      constants.FETCH_FAIL]
    }
  }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_HANDLERS = (prefix) => {
  return {
    [`${prefix}_${constants.DESTROY_START}`]: (state, action) => {
      return state.set('destroying', true)
    },

    [`${prefix}_${constants.DESTROY_SUCCESS}`]: (state, action) => {
      return state.set('destroying', false)
    },

    [`${prefix}_${constants.DESTROY_FAIL}`]: (state, action) => {
      return state.set('destroying', false)
    },

    [`${prefix}_${constants.FETCH_START}`]: (state, action) => {
      return state.set('loading', true)
    },

    [`${prefix}_${constants.FETCH_SUCCESS}`]: (state, { payload }) => {
      const users = payload.entities.user
      const userIds = payload.result.user
      const roles = payload.entities.role

      // It's a single record fetch
      const user = users[userIds[0]]

      return state.merge({
        loading: false,
        record: Record({ user: Record(user)(), roles: Record(roles)() })()
      })
    },

    [`${prefix}_${constants.FETCH_FAIL}`]: (state, action) => {
      return state.set('loading', false)
    }
  }

}

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = Record({
  destroying: false,
  loading: true, // initially true so will only go to false upong user loaded
  record: Record({ user: Record({})(), roles: List([]) })()
})()

const userReducer = (prefix = 'USER') => {
  if (prefix === undefined || prefix.length < 1) {
    throw new Error('prefix must be defined')
  }

  return (state = initialState, action) => {
    const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS(prefix)[`${prefix}_${action.type}`]
    return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
  }
}

export default userReducer
```

## Edit user reducer and action creators (edit_user.js):

```
import normalize from 'jsonapi-normalizer'
import { api, authenticatedHeaders } from 'api'
import { RSAA } from 'redux-api-middleware'
import { List, Record } from 'immutable'
import * as constants from './constants'

// ------------------------------------
// Actions
// ------------------------------------
export const updateUser = (userId, params = {}) => {
  // Uses redux-api-middleware. see: https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: api.users.update.path(userId),
      method: api.users.update.method,
      headers: (state) => authenticatedHeaders(state.session.authorization.token),
      types: [
      constants.USER_UPDATE_START,
      constants.USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
      constants.USER_UPDATE_FAIL]
    }
  }
}

// TODO: see how to reuse this from the user.js file!
export const fetchUser = (userId) => {
  // Uses redux-api-middleware. see: https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: api.users.show.path(userId),
      method: api.users.show.method,
      headers: (state) => authenticatedHeaders(state.session.authorization.token),
      types: [
      constants.USER_FETCH_START,
      {
        type: constants.USER_FETCH_SUCCESS,
        payload: (action, state, res) => {
          return res.json().then(json => normalize(json))
        }
      },
      constants.USER_FETCH_FAIL]
    }
  }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [constants.USER_UPDATE_START]: (state, action) => {
    return state.set('loading', true)
  },

  [constants.USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
    return state.set('loading', false)
  },

  [constants.USER_UPDATE_FAIL]: (state, action) => {
    return state.set('loading', false)
  },

  // TODO: this reducers are the same as user.js, reuse them!!
  [constants.USER_FETCH_START]: (state, action) => {
    return state.set('loading', true)
  },

  [constants.USER_FETCH_SUCCESS]: (state, { payload }) => {
    const users = payload.entities.user
    const userIds = payload.result.user
    const roles = payload.entities.role

    // It's a single record fetch
    const user = users[userIds[0]]

    return state.merge({
      loading: false,
      record: Record({ user: Record(user)(), roles: Record(roles)() })()
    })
  },

  [constants.USER_FETCH_FAIL]: (state, action) => {
    return state.set('loading', false)
  }

}

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = Record({
  loading: true, // initially true so will only go to false upong user loaded
  record: Record({ user: Record({})(), roles: List([]) })()
})()

export default function editUserReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

As you can see in the TODO's in the code, i want to be able to reuse those parts of reducer and action creator since it's not only reusable for an entity basic operations, but for any generic CRUD operation on any resource that my application may use!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new function and with the differences (from what I can see, the constants) extracted to the parameters, either as a higher order function (like what I did below), or combine them with the existing parameter (`userId`):

```
export const createFetchUser = (fetchStart, fetchSuccess, fetchFail) => userId =>
  // Uses redux-api-middleware. see: https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware
  ({
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: api.users.show.path(userId),
      method: api.users.show.method,
      headers: state => authenticatedHeaders(state.session.authorization.token),
      types: [
        fetchStart,
        {
          type: fetchSuccess,
          payload: (action, state, res) => res.json().then(json => normalize(json)),
        },
        fetchFail,
      ],
    },
  });
```

You can then import this function in your `user.js` and `edit_user.js` to create the `fetchUser` function for different constants, eg. for `user.js`:

```
export const fetchUser = userId =>
  createFetchUser(constants.FETCH_START, constants.FETCH_SUCCESS, constants.FETCH_FAIL);
```

You can do something similar for your reducers.

Comment: I ended up using this: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic + a mix of your answer, by using a prefix instead of passing each action type (fetchStart, fetchSuccess, etc) to the action creator. I will accept your answer, however it would be nice to have some kind of structure to share the reducer prefix with the action creator prefix, without having to pass it to the action creators as a param when calling them